# Why can't I get T4 templates to generate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I am trying to create a T4 template, but I am stuck at the very first stages.  I can't get any output to be generated.  Right now I have the most basic template

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
Testing
```

When I save this file, nothing is generated.  I then tried to right click on the `.tt` file, and the context menu doesn't show a "Run Custom Tool" menu item, as it does when I right click T4MVC's .tt file.

What do I do to get output to be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, figured it out.  I had to click on my `.tt` file, open the properties, and set the `CustomTool` property to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`.